# How to use information from a scope elsewhere

Tags: c#, scope

I'd like to use the information gathered from `ReadLine()` in another code scope.
I've created a menu and I'm using an if-statement. 
If I want to use the information gathered in option 1 in the menu, and write it into option 2, how do I go about doing that?

```
if (selectMenu == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What item will you put in the backpack?");
    //Console.ReadLine();
    string item = Console.ReadLine();
}
else if (selectMenu == 2)
{

}
```

So basically I want to be able to use `item` in the `else if`.

Comment: What is a "code block" exactly?

Comment: Probably some code explaining your question would help :)

Comment: Truth be told this is a direct translation that I thought it would be from Swedish. I'm sorry if this confused you but what I mean is these { }

Comment: { } brackets are used in many different places: namespaces, classes, methods, if-statements, loops, etc.  So please be more specific.  **What are you trying to do?**

Comment: No, update your question with more information.  Don't put substantive information in the comments section.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare the variable in the outside scope:

```
string item = null;
if (selectMenu == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What item will you put in the backpack?");
    item = Console.ReadLine();
}
else if (selectMenu == 2)
{
}

... you could use the item variable here but it will have its default value of null 
if selectMenu was different than 1 because in this example we assign it
only inside the first if.
```

Comment: I see, then how do I assign the value given in option 1 to option 2?